# Multiple click events on multiple axes chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a multiple axes chart like this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

In my particular case, I only want the click handler for the bar chart, and not the other ones.

I tried using

```
          series:
            cursor: 'pointer'
            point:
              events:
                click: ->
```

But that hooks on to all the lines.

Does anyone know if it is possible to have a different click handler for each line/bar/point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set click event for column type, not series (which is genereal to all of series type).

http://jsfiddle.net/agnHV/

```
plotOptions:{
            column:{
                point:{
                    events:{
                        click:function(){
                        alert('aaa');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: cool thanks, ill check this out. out of curiosity, what would you do in the case of multiple column charts (stacked columns)?

Comment: In the fact for each series you can set different events: `series: [{ name: ' ', data: [], point: { events: { click: function() { ... } } } }]`